# UndescoreJS - Convert Object Properties Into Arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, chart.js

The case is simple - I've got a list of objects:

```
[
{"id":"0001","status":"prod"},  
{"id":"0002","status":"prod"},  
{"id":"0003","status":"prod"},  
{"id":"0004","status":"prod"},  
{"id":"0005","status":"dev"},  
{"id":"0006","status":"dev"}
]
```

when I user `_.groupBy('status')`, the result is:

```
{
    prod: [{"id":"0001","status":"prod"},  
        {"id":"0002","status":"prod"},  
        {"id":"0003","status":"prod"},  
        {"id":"0004","status":"prod"}],
    dev: [{"id":"0005","status":"dev"},  
        {"id":"0006","status":"dev"}]
}
```

But I need a result like the code below to send to Chart.js (using Underscorejs):

```
{
    legend: ['prod','dev'],
    data: [4,2]  // Array Length  
}
```

How can I use Underscore.js to resolve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one chain, just for fun.

```
_.chain(data)
  .groupBy('status')
  .mapObject(x => x.length)
  .pairs()
  .unzip()
  .zip(['legend', 'data'])
  .map(x => x.reverse())
  .object()
  .value();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need one more step:

```
 var output = {
     legend: [],
     data: []
 }
 _.chain(rawData).groupBy('status').each(function(value,key){
       output.legend.push(key);
       output.legend.push(data.length);
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var legend = _.uniq(_.pluck(data, 'status'));
var groupedData = _.groupBy(data, 'status');

var result = {
    legend: legend,
    data: _.map(legend, function(status) {
        return groupedData[status].length;
    })
};
```